# How to store a datetime using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I made this to store data of some meetings but I want the field `"date"` to store values as `datetime` like in a mysql base. How can I do this?

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose')
const Schema= mongoose.Schema

const Meets= mongoose.model('Meet', new Schema({
    id1: String,
    id2: String,
    date: Date

}))

module.exports= Users
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema should be in below format for store Meeting time in DateTime format.

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose')
const Schema= mongoose.Schema

const Meets= mongoose.model('Meet', new Schema({
   // First meeting recipient
   id1: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },

   // Second meeting recipient
   id2: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },

   // Date and Time of meeting
   date: { type: Date, required: true }
}))

module.exports= Meets
```

Now, When you will make an entry in Meets collection, You will find below format of date key in your mongo database:

> ISODate("2017-04-02T15:30:00Z")

This represents that the above is in ISO Date format which gives time into UTC format. To convert it in your local time format, you can do below step:

> new Date(meet.date).toLocaleString();

Also, you can set property {timestamps:true} in your schema, which will additionally add **createdAt** and **updatedAt** field in your collection, which will automatically get updated at creation and each update.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

What kind of date format you want to store? If you want it to be stored in milliseconds, then you can set `timestamps` option to `true` like this:

```
const Meets= mongoose.model('Meet', new Schema({
    id1: {String},
    id2: {String},
}, {timestamps:true}))
```